# Scan a particular line in a text-file with fscanf in C?

Tags: c, scanf

I want to do a search in a textfile with fscanf.
It's a number that I'm searching for, and the numbers are in order by value.
Therefore, I want to do a binary search, starting from the middle and so on.
My idea was to first count the number of lines, divided by two to find the middle.
But how to tell fscanf to look at that line?

```
int seach_textfile(struct data *ean13, unsigned long long int *input)
{
    FILE *fp_read = fopen("data.tex", "r");
    unsigned long long int read, n_lines;

    // count lines
    n_lines = 0;
    while (fscanf(fp_read,"\n") == 1)
    {
        n_lines++;
    }

    int n_line_low = 0;
    int n_line_mid;
    int n_line_high =n_lines;

    while(n_line_high>n_line_low)
    {
        n_line_mid; = (n_line_low + n_line_high)/2;
        fscanf(fp_read,"%lld \n", read).... at n_line_mid  // <----here!! (only to read first entr on line)
        if(*input > read)
        {
            n_line_low = n_line_mid +1;
        }
        else
        {
            n_line_high = n_line_mid;
        }
    } 
    if(*input == read)
    {
        fscanf(fp_read,"%lld %s %s %s",*ean13->ean,*ean13->country,*ean13->manufacture,*ean13->product).... at n_line_mid  // <----here!!
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (fscanf(fp_read,"\n") == 1)` does not count _lines_.   `fscanf(fp_read,"\n")` reads and consumes all leading white-space.

Comment: You can read line by line using fgets and for each line read (into a buffer provided to fgets), use sscanf to search in the line. And test the return of the functions.

Comment: If you're willing to read the whole file to count the lines, why aren't you looking for the information as you read it?  And during the binary search operations, how are you going to avoid reading all the lines up to the line number you're searching for?  Remember, lines vary in length a lot.

Comment: You cannot perform a binary search efficiently on the file unless you can move to the starts of random lines efficiently.  That requires either fixed-length lines or an index.  If you have either of those then you do not need to read the file to count lines.  If you do not have either of those then it is easiest and most efficient to simply perform a linear scan of the file, because you would have to do that anyway to count lines or build an index.

Comment: Numbers, as text, are not uniformly spaced in a file.  Perhaps find the file  byte length, and then apply binary search.  Each halving of the length may point to a middle of a line, then search backwards (or forwards) for a line beginning, then read the number.  I do not see a highly portable solution to this task with reading as a text file and seeking by binary search is UB.  Instead could read the file recording the offset of each line start in an array and then binary searching on that array.  Good luck.

Comment: how big the file is?

Comment: @JohnBollinger On the contrary: If you've got a text file with mixed-length lines, you *can* still perform nicely efficient binary search (and without an index); you just can't assume that your fseeks or lseeks will hit line beginnings exactly. See https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/src/#bsearch if curious.

Comment: (Now, it's true, if you're using `fseek` you're going to have to make the less-than-strictly-portable assumption that `fseek` deals in actual offsets as opposed to cookies, and you kind of have to assume that the line lengths aren't unreasonably long.)

Comment: @SteveSummit, I suppose it depends to some extent on the question you are asking and on the structure of the file.  If the question is merely "is the target present in the file?" then you can make some headway by using bytewise splitting of the search space, with a search-around for line boundaries and some careful handling when the intervals approach the size of the lines.  This is non-trivial, and probably beyond the skill that I (perhaps uncharitably) attribute to the OP.  But if the question is "on what line number does the target appear?" then that's another story.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Oh, I think you can do more than "make some headway" — that `bsearch` program I linked works properly, I think, under all circumstances. Now, there's no question that it's not easy. (I've got some marvelous tales I like to tell about that implementation, which I'll spare you.)  And you're right, although you can find matching lines, you have no idea what the absolute (`grep -n` style) line number might be.

Answer (score 0):

OP's code fails to find the line count as `fscanf(fp_read,"\n")` only reads leading white-space and block on first on-white-space.

Line count is not that useful anyways as it only search to find an approximate location to seek.  File length would afford the same.

---

**Alternative**

1. Open the text file in *binary mode*.
2. Quickly determine its length.  (e.g. sum of repeated `fread()`s, or [`fstat()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) if available).)
3. `left = 0; right = length-1`
4. `mid = (left+right)/2` Use `fseek(mid)`.
5. `fgetc()` or `fgets()` to line end: e.g. Look for `'\n'` or `EOF`.
6. Read number.  If match, we are done.
7. If too big, `right = mid - 1`.  If too small, `left = ftell()`.
8. If `right >= left`, loop back to step 4.
9. Fail - number not found.

Check I/O function return values along the way.

If code needs to look for another number, omit step 2 as the file length is already known.

Comment: So I use EOF, get read-position somehow... go half way back.... and go to start of line... is that possible?

Comment: @Too_Old_To_Get_IT There is no simple or predefined way to "go to start of line".  After seeking, you are probably  going to have to read a block of characters — me, I'd use `fread` — then search inside it for the `\n`'s that mark line boundaries.  You'll have to handle the cases that the block you read contains zero, one, or more than one line boundary.  It's tricky, and there are a number of cases to get right, but it's possible to make it work, and it can work well.  But it's not an easy problem.

Comment: @Too_Old_To_Get_IT ".... and go to start of line... is that possible?"  Yes, possible.  I see going to next line easier.

Answer (score 0):

I would read all the lines first and store them in the linked list. Then you can do whatever you want. You can add `prev` pointer as well if you going backwards.

```
typedef struct line
{
    struct line *next;
    char line[];
}line;


#define MAXLINE (8*1024)


line *readFile(FILE *fi, int removeLF)
{
    char *workbuff = malloc(MAXLINE);
    line *head = NULL, **current = &head;
    if(fi && workbuff)
    {
        while(fgets(workbuff, MAXLINE, fi))
        {
            size_t len = strlen(workbuff);
            *current = malloc(sizeof(**current) + len + 1);
            if(current)
            {
                memcpy(current[0] -> line, workbuff, len + 1);
                if(removeLF && current[0] -> line[len - 1] == '\n') current[0] -> line[len - 1] = 0;
                current = &current[0] -> next;
            }
        }
    }
    *current = NULL;
    return head;
}

void print(line *lines)
{
    size_t cline = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("line no %zu = `%s`\n", ++cline, lines -> line);
        lines = lines -> next;
    }while(lines);
}

  
int main(void)
{
    line *file = readFile(stdin, 1);
    print(file);
}
```

Comment: Sure, but if you read all the lines then you can determine through that process whether the wanted item is present, and if so then on which line.  If those are the only questions to answer then there is no point in storing the file contents in memory in any form.